# Run python (selenium) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have python code that I have written here using selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')
driver.get('https://fantasy.espn.com/football/players/add?leagueId=1589782588')

players = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@class="AnchorLink link clr-link pointer"]')
position = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class="playerinfo__playerpos ttu"]')
players_list = []
position_list = []
for p in range(len(players)):
    players_list.append(players[p].text)
    position_list.append(position[p].text)
print(players_list)
```

I want to call this python script in my js file so I wrote:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

let runPy = new Promise(function(success, nosuccess) {

    const { spawn } = require('child_process');
    const pyprog = spawn('python', ['scrape.py']);

    pyprog.stdout.on('data', function(data) {

        success(data);
    });

    pyprog.stderr.on('data', (data) => {

        nosuccess(data);
    });
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {

    res.write('welcome\n');

    runPy.then(function(fromRunpy) {
        console.log(fromRunpy.toString());
        res.end(fromRunpy);
    });
})

app.listen(4000, () => console.log('Application listening on port 4000!'))
```

This code only opens up the website, how can I actually print the list from the python script?

Comment: Why not use same selenium in JS directly?

Comment: Resolving your promise on the first `data` event might not be what you want. Either just stream the python output to the http response directly, or consume it in its entirety before resolving your promise.

Comment: @Justinas would you be able to help with the JS equivalent for the python code?